# Script AWS para deletar snapshot maior que 7 dias

Tags: script, amazon-aws, powershell

Preciso fazer um script para deletar minhas snapshots no meu `AWS` maiores que 7 dias.

Para realizar a criação uso esse script, espero que ajude.

```
AWS ec2 create-image --no-reboot --instance-id i-131e8e06 --name "SITELINK-BKP-DIARIO-%date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%" --description "SITELINK-BKP-DIARIO"
```

Comment: Esse script funciona ou está com problema?

Comment: Então man, esse scrip que eu falei é o que eu uso para realizar a criação da imagem. Eu preciso de um para deletar essas imagens criadas maiores de 7 dias

Comment: Isso aí não tem cara de powershell, posso estar enganado

Comment: Esse esta em dos os o script para deletar pode ser em powershell ou docs nao tem problema, vc manja ?

Answer (score 0):

Só para não confundir mais ninguém (como me confundiu ao ler o título), trata-se de AMI's e não snapshots (EBS Snapshots do EC2).

Dito isso, eu posso sugerir o uso de tags:

1. adicione tags na AMI após ela ser criada, usando `ec2 create-tags id_da_nova_ami --tag timestamp=timestamp_de_agora --tag=tipoDeAMI=SITELINK_BKP`
2. na hora de achar as AMIs obsoletas, faça uma busca filtrando pela tag `tipoDeAMI`, assim: `ec2 describe-images --filter "tag-tipoDeAMI=SITELINK_BKP"`
3. processe as AMIs retornadas e veja quais tem a tag `timestamp` menores que o valor mínimo que você quer manter. Para essas timestamps eu usaria algo padrão como o Unix epoch (numero de segundos ou dias desde 1/1/1970)

Pra ser sincero, eu normalmente escrevo meus scripts para AWS usando Python com o SDK Boto (oficial). Eu não me arriscaria a tentar mostrar como fazer o que listei acima usando bash ou powershell.